# Problem with GUI error tkinter while reading digital inputs through modbus tcp/ip

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, nonetype

I created a program that reads modbus tcp/ip digital inputs data from a PLC and represents it on a GUI.
The problem is that i get NoneType Error while running the code.
The code is:

```
import Modbus_PLC as md
from tkinter import *


class DigitalInputLamp():

def __init__(self, x1, y1, label, img1, img2):
    self.x1 = x1
    self.y1 = y1

    # Are images same for all lamps?  Make a class variable?
    self.images = [img1, img2]
    self.label = label
    # Placing widget should probably happen outside the class
    # when the widget is created
    self.label.place(x=self.x1, y=self.y1)
    self.state = 0
    self.label.config(image=self.images[self.state])

def show_state(self, state):
    if state != self.state:
        self.state = state
        self.label.config(image=self.images[self.state])
 #############################################################
def update_lamps(lamps, period, canvas):
   digital_inputs = md.rd_dig_in(0, len(lamps))
   for i, lamp in enumerate(lamps):
      lamp.show_state(digital_inputs[i])
   canvas.after(period, lamps)


def Main_Page():

root1 = Tk()
root1.title("GUI App")

canvas44 = Canvas(root1, height=512, width=898)
canvas44.pack()
img_butt8 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Omer\\Desktop\\Green_led1.png')
img_butt9 = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Omer\\Desktop\\Red_led1.png')
label1 = Label(canvas44)
label2 = Label(canvas44)
label3 = Label(canvas44)
label4 = Label(canvas44)
label5 = Label(canvas44)
label_list=[label1,label2,label3,label4,label5]
# Make a bunch of lamps and start updating
lamps = [DigitalInputLamp(i*80,10,label_list[i], img_butt8,img_butt9) for i in range(5)]
update_lamps(lamps, 500, canvas44)

root1.mainloop()





Main_Page()
```

The Error i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Omer/test.py", line 58, in <module>
Main_Page()
File "C:/Users/Omer/test.py", line 50, in Main_Page
update_lamps(lamps, 500, canvas44)
File "C:/Users/Omer/test.py", line 28, in update_lamps
lamp.show_state(digital_inputs[i])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I dont understand what im doing wrong , and why digital_input is a NoneType object

Comment: This is telling you that `digital_inputs` is `None`.

Comment: Yes , i know i just dont understand why its None , it actually supposed to be True or False as it reads the digital inputs registers from the PLC using Modbus.